# Sending Data From One Workbook to Another with Command Button

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code wtihin a command button to send data from one workbook to a specific cell in another workbook.  This worked when I originally tested it, but after I did 2 things:  pasted the same code with updated cell references in other command buttons throughout the workbook, and change the "open workbook" command to an "if" command in an attempt to account for the destination workbook already being opened, I started getting a "Subscript Out of Range" message.  Can you help?

```
Dim wkbDest, wkbSource As Workbook
    ret = ("<insert file path here>")
    If ret = False Then
    Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open("<insert file path here>")
    Else
    Set wkbDest = Workbooks("<insert file name here>")
    End If
    Set wkbSource = ThisWorkbook
Dim f As Range, rwNum
    Set f = wkbDest.Worksheets("Exhibit C").Range("B:B").Find(What:=wkbSource.Worksheets("ReferenceData1").Range("S3"), lookat:=xlWhole)

If Range("C19").Value = "Pass" Then
    wkbDest.Worksheets("Exhibit C").Cells(f.Row, "E").Value = Range("B19").Value
ElseIf Range("C19").Value = "Fail" Then

End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's easier for me to point out the flaws in your code than ask a bunch of questions to fix it. Take a look at the comments I've included to your code:**

```
Dim wkbDest, wkbSource As Workbook '<--- wkbDest is Variant here.
    ret = ("<insert file path here>")
    If ret = False Then '<-- might not be wrong, but why is this boolean?
        Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open("<insert file path here>")
    Else
        Set wkbDest = Workbooks("<insert file name here>")
    End If
    Set wkbSource = ThisWorkbook
Dim f As Range, rwNum '<--- rwNum is Variant
    Set f = wkbDest.Worksheets("Exhibit C").Range("B:B").Find(What:=wkbSource.Worksheets("ReferenceData1").Range("S3"), lookat:=xlWhole) '<----don't use Worksheets, use Sheets()

If Range("C19").Value = "Pass" Then '<---- you aren't defining where this range is (which workbook, which sheet)
    wkbDest.Worksheets("Exhibit C").Cells(f.Row, "E").Value = Range("B19").Value '<-----what if 'f' isn't found? you have nothing to catch that
ElseIf Range("C19").Value = "Fail" Then '<----- you need to define this range as well

End If
```

---

**This is how I would change your code. (Removing ret)**

```
Sub SendData()
    Dim wbSource As Workbook: Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wbPath As String: wbPath = "C:\ExampleFolder"
    Dim wbDestName As String: wbDestName = "ExampleWorkbook.xls"
    Dim wbDest As Workbook: Set wbDest = Workbooks(wbDestName)
    Dim f As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Verify workbook exists at target loctation and open it
    If wbDest Is Nothing Then
        If Right(wbPath, 1) <> "\" Then wbPath = wbPath & "\"
        If Dir(wbPath & wbDestName) = "" Then
            MsgBox "Workbook " & wbDest & " at location " & wbPath & " could not be found.", _
                vbCritical, "Missing Workbook"
            Exit Sub
        Else: Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(wbPath & wbDestName)
        End If
    End If

    Set f = wbDest.Sheets("Exhibit C").Range("B:B").Find(What:=wbSource.Sheets("ReferenceData1").Range("S3").Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    'If f is found, do stuff, otherwise exit
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        If UCase(wbSource.Range("C19").Value) = UCase("Pass") Then
            wbDest.Sheets("Exhibit C").Cells(f.Row, "E").Value = wbSource.Range("B19").Value
        ElseIf UCase(wbSource.Range("C19").Value) = UCase("Fail") Then
            'some fail code
        End If
    Else: MsgBox "Could not find " & wbSource.Sheets("ReferenceData1").Range("S3").Value, vbCritical, "No Search Result"
    End If

    wbDest.Save
    wbDest.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Tyeler.  Why is it Boolean?  Frankly, I am not sure.  I am a 100% self taught vba programmer, and in all of my research for modeling this code, it was there.  Additonally, I've messed with the code a little bit, and it works great if the wkbDest is already open, but not if it is closed.  When stepping into the code, "ret" is coming back as "False", but for some reason it is still stepping into the "Else" step.  Thoughts?

Comment: I like what youre trying to do here, and i want to help you get a finished product. I am away from my computer and may not have access to it until tomorrow or sunday. I too am completely self taught, and Ive written a few snippets of code that i think youd be interested in if youre okay waiting until i get back to my computer :)

Comment: I updated the code to show how I would change it. Ive included some statements to catch errors if values aren't acceptable.

Comment: I never responded, but this is great and thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you out! Thanks for accepting this as the answer!